# Obtaining a 2D index from a 3D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy array that is (7 x 325 x 255). The seven are different bands from an image, and the 325 and 448 are rows and columns (i.e. pixels). X is an example of my setup.

```
     x = x = np.random.randint(5, size=(7,325,255))
```

I'm trying to create a two-dimensional index (325,255) using np.where() from all 7 bands, where the values are equal to my no data parameter, which is -9999. My argument is the following:

```
    y = np.asarray(np.where(x == -9999))
```

However, when I print the shape of y, I get the following, which should be (325, 255):

```
    (3, 580125)
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to tackle this?
Much thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get indices where _all_ bands equal the special value or _any_?

Comment: Not entirely sure I'm following the question... so you have a 3d-array x of (length=7, width=325, height=255) which contains a bunch of values, one of which is x(l,w,h) = -9999. And you want to generate some 'y' array which can be represented in a 2d array which inherits the width and height of your 3d array. What exactly are you hoping to populate the y array with? What information is it supposed to hold?

Comment: @Matthias It would probably be any, sorry should have clarified that .

Comment: @MichaelGreen The final product is an index that shows where I have a value of -9999 across any band.

Comment: @fotxoa So if I understand correctly, you want a boolean 2d array that is True if any -9999 occurs?

Comment: @MatthiasOssadnik yes! That's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `any` to aggregate over the bands. This yields the required 2d boolean array:

```
y = np.any(x == -9999, axis=0)
```